# My hot and cold water are connected in the output of my water heater

Tags: water-heater

Never seen this before, the Cold water is connected to the hot water for the output of my water heater. Any idea what this is?
[image]

Comment: Your water heater appears to have been installed perpendicular to gravity.  This can't be good for it.

Comment: Can we get a close up (right side up this time please) of the 3 way junction coming off the hot side?  That looks like it might be a 3 way diverter valve.

Comment: That looks a lot like a "Get your teen to free the darn shower" hack to me. Basically a way to easily cut off the hot water supply to the house.

Comment: Oooh now THAT's an interesting idea, @Jeffrey - lol - no more hot water for you kiddo!!!

Comment: I've reoriented gravity...

Comment: Why are you changing the water heater at this time? If you are going to do this, plan in detail how you are to connect the new heater. Looking at your set up I would say that unless you have a cut-off valve on the cold supply already, it is a code requirement that you must install one. I would use a ball valve above where the cold water supply divides for the heater and the thermostatic mixing valve. Then use bendable supply lines to connect to the tank. One big sin is to sweat a fitting in place on the top of the tank. Decades ago OK, but now most tanks have a warning to not use a torch there

Comment: What a nice place to work--plenty of room!

Answer (score 7):

This is a thermostatic mixing valve, and it is a beneficial and useful thing to have. The temperature of the water in the tank heater should be 140 F to prevent the growth of Legionellae bacteria, but this is in general too hot for most uses in the house. The solution is to mix cold water into the hot to bring the temperature in the distribution system down to a lower temp, usually 120 F.

Lowering the temperature in the hot water delivery system also increases the service life of valves and piping.

Some of these valves are designed and specified to be installed at or near the hot water heater, others were designed to service only a single use point, usually a shower. I believe the later type is not much used anymore because all modern shower valves have a thermostatic mixing valve incorporated into the valve.

For example, [Watts thermostatic mixing valve](https://www.grainger.com/product/29HZ40?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916793557!!!g!82128171357!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180815145501:s).

**EDIT** BTW this water heater is apparently plumbed with copper all the way to the tank. At one time this was considered the first rate way to plumb it, but no longer is.  The reason is because this makes a conducting connection between the steel WH tank and the copper plumbing. This can cause accelerated corrosion of the water heater or the copper plumbing.

Much better *and easier* is to use bendable supply connections which have a so called "dielectric coupling" meaning the tank and plumbing are insulated from each other.

Also you should have a cut-off valve in the cold water inlet to the WH. I *believe* it should be located ahead of the T for cold supply to the thermostatic mixing valve, but I am not positive and you had better check on this with someone experienced in plumbing with TMVs.

Comment: Interesting! I had never seen one of these before!

Comment: I suggest that you verify that the TMV is connected correctly according to the indications on the valve H for hot in, C for cold in, M for mixed out.